# SQLPlus one-line questions

Tags: sqlplus

I inherited some sqlplus code that no longer is valid in our Workload Automation tool. It needs to either be converted to a script and called, or a one-line command. I absolutely understand how to do the first (fairly basic). But if I wanted to convert to one line, is my thinking correct?

```
sqlplus -s myID/pwd <<EOF
define start_date=$start_date;
define end_date=$end_date;
define max_depth=$max_depth;
define min_units=$min_units;
@/app/myapp/sql/forecast
EOF
```

to convert to one line, is it as simple as:

```
sqlplus -s myID/pwd < define start_date=$start_date; define   end_date=$end_date; define max_depth=$max_depth; define min_units=$min_units; @/app/myapp/sql/forecast
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your one line is still be running from a shell script, which the call to `sqlplus` suggests, you can use a pipe rather than a redirect to pass the commands to SQL*Plus:

```
printf "define start_date=$start_date\ndefine end_date=$end_date\ndefine max_depth=$max_depth\ndefine min_units=$min_units\n@/app/myapp/sql/forecast" | sqlplus -s myID/pwd
```

Or perhaps *slightly* more readably, which you may disagree about:

```
printf "define start_date=%s\ndefine end_date=%d\ndefine max_depth=%d\ndefine min_units=%d\n@%s" $start_date $end_date $max_depth $min_units /app/myapp/sql/forecast | sqlplus -s myID/pwd
```

You need line breaks rather than semicolons to separate the `define` client commands from each other and the `@`.

Comment: Hi Alex,

It is actually the NewLine and Carriage Return that is causing the issue.  

I am curious if the \n will work.  Off to test and see what occurs. 

Thanks.

Comment: @Pat - it might be helpful to edit your question to explain the issue you are actually having, and what your tool is.

Comment: Alex--This is for a product called Control-M. The version was upgraded and doesn't allow for newline or returns when using a command line. The product screams about it.  

You answered my question that with the define statements and the semi-colons, this doesn't appear it can be done via a single command.

Thanks for your help.